# How to compare AJAX value and PHP value in AJAX success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var assign_sales_id = $('#assign_sales_id').val();
$('#'+id).children('td[data-target=assign_sales_id]').text(assign_sales_id);
```

I want to check equality of (select name from users where `id = '$('#assign_sales_id').val()')`

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You can't compare JS and PHP values on the client. All you can do is make an AJAX request, but you've already done that... so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If your file is filename.php then do this

```
var assign_sales_id = $('#assign_sales_id').val();
if(assign_sales_id == "<?php echo $somevalue ?>")
{

}
```

if your file is filename.js then put php variable into any hidden field in your page and then do this

```
 var assign_sales_id = $('#assign_sales_id').val();
    if(assign_sales_id == $('#some_php_value').val())
    {

    }
```